# Tests fail when "mvn clean install" but doesn't when "mvn install" - Drools project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, drools

I followed the official drools tutorial for a rule-based system and then I tried to make it a maven project.

I though I succeed at doing so since I could run all the test, the problem comes when I try to **mvn clean install** it.

After doing so, the tests don't pass anymore in eclipse or **mvn install** but after **project->clean** tests pass again running in JUnit eclipse UI and **mvn install**.

I'm guessing the problem maybe comes from the maven scope when I **mvn clean install** it?

The error is the same for all tests, Unexpected Global, I paste the trace here:

```
testRuleFlow2(droolscours.TestLesson4)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected global [showResult]
        at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.setGlobal(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1199)
        at droolscours.TestLesson4.testRuleFlow2(TestLesson4.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

- The showResult class is in src/main/java/util.
- Tests are in src/test/java.
- Rules are in src/test/rules.

I also paste my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Drools-MavenTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>Drools-MavenTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>drools-tutorial/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>drools-tutorial/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbpm/jbpm-kie-services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-kie-services</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbpm/jbpm-bpmn2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbpm/jbpm-runtime-manager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-runtime-manager</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I don't know if some more info is required, if so ask me for it please I'm kinda new in maven.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is because you didn't clear persistent state after test.

Comment: @holi-java excuse me, could you elaborate please? How exactly do I do that

Comment: First follow the conventions in Maven means source code in `src/main/java` and test code in `src/test/java` and don't try to configure things you don't understand so remove `<sourceDirectory>drools-tutorial/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>` also `<testSourceDirectory>drools-tutorial/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>`

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you for your answer. I was able to fix it, maybe it was the things to remove in pom, I also reorganized my code in packages as you said. TY again.